# CSS: text-overflow: ellipsis with reactJS and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having a trouble with ellipsis in IE 11.

I am working with ReactJS to render data from API, this is my CSS

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

It works very well on Chrome.

The problem comes from IE after the page loaded, the CSS does not work correctly, I cannot see any ellipsis. If I use inspect element tool to disable the line

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

and enable again -> work well in IE. I think the problem because IE does not reload anything after the content text was changed.

Does anyone have an idea about this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is working on IE11  JsFiddle that I've made for your case

HTML:

```
<h1 id="test">Initial long text coming  here to test ellipsis</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:150px;
 }
 h1:hover {
    overflow:visible;
 }
```

JS:

```
setTimeout( function (){
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='New long text coming here to test ellipsis';}, 5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbppL/1277/

If it is IE10, IE9 you may try adding: " -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;"

And here is same code with react:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/168244/

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working, so I think I am having another problem.